# numpy - tensor multiplication product

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I have a 4 x 4 matrix

```
import numpy as np
c = np.random.rand((4,4))
```

I want to create an 100 x 4 x 4 x 100 tensor such that when the first an last index are equal, I get back my matrix else I get zeros.

I can do this in a loop as

```
Z = np.zeros((100, 4, 4, 100))
for i in range(100):
    Z[i, :, :, i] = c
```

is there a better way to do this? I tried looking at np.tensordot and np.einsum but could not figure it out.

Thanks,
Sahil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
n = 100
Zout = np.zeros((n, 4, 4, n))
I = np.arange(n)
Zout[I,:,:,I] = c
```

With `eye-masking` -

```
n = 100
mask = np.eye(n, dtype=bool)
Zout = np.zeros((n, 4, 4, n))
Zout.transpose(0,3,1,2)[mask] = c
```

Timings -

```
In [72]: c = np.random.rand(4,4)

In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: n = 100
    ...: Zout = np.zeros((n, 4, 4, n))
    ...: I = np.arange(n)
    ...: Zout[I,:,:,I] = c
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.5 µs per loop

In [74]: %%timeit
    ...: n = 100
    ...: mask = np.eye(n, dtype=bool)
    ...: Zout = np.zeros((n, 4, 4, n))
    ...: Zout.transpose(0,3,1,2)[mask] = c
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping there would be some function that would take `np.eye(100)` and `c` to come up with `Z`

Comment: @SahilPuri Indexing with np.eye won't be that efficient, I would think.